# GLViewWidget Viewport Size

Tags: opengl, viewport, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, maximize

I am unable to set viewport to desired dimensions. Despite specifying (1980 x 1080), the resultant dimensions are (1366 x 855). The 3D examples in pyqtgraph too do not show full screen and are located at lower left corner only.

```
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore    

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

view = gl.GLViewWidget()
view.opts['viewport'] =  (0, 0, 1920, 1080)
view.showMaximized()

view.setMaximumSize(1920, 1080)
print ("%d %d" % (view.height() ,  view.width()))
view.setWindowTitle('3D Matrix Visualization')


## create three grids, add each to the view
xgrid = gl.GLGridItem()
ygrid = gl.GLGridItem()
zgrid = gl.GLGridItem()
view.addItem(xgrid)
view.addItem(ygrid)
view.addItem(zgrid)

## rotate x and y grids to face the correct direction
xgrid.rotate(90, 0, 1, 0)
ygrid.rotate(90, 1, 0, 0)

## scale each grid differently
xgrid.scale(0.2, 0.1, 0.1)
ygrid.scale(0.2, 0.1, 0.1)
zgrid.scale(0.1, 0.2, 0.1)
```

If I run the code without changing viewport settings, the parent window, by the virtue of `showMaximized()`, appears full screen. But the drawable area is confined to 1/4 of the screen in the lower left corner.

`view.opts['viewport'] =  (0, 0, 1920, 1080)`

Using above code, does make drawable area larger but then it is not large enough to cover maximized screen. It is 1366x855. The grid/axis appears in upper right corner and not in the center of 1366x855. In the default mode, the grid/axis appears in the center of the 1/4 drawable area.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the actual drawable area by setting glClearColor to something visible, like red? Have you tried calling glViewport directly within your render code?

Comment: Tried both and there seems to be no effect.
`glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1)`
`glViewport(0, 0, 2880, 1800)`

Comment: Is this a retina screen? MacOS X has some wierd rules about window/view sizes and viewport dimensions. If that's not it, I'm out of ideas other than to read the source for GLGridItem

Comment: Yes it is. It does increase the drawable viewport area but everything is translated off screen. I could translate the grid to center through hit and trial but then I need to translate everything. Very annoying. I read the code for `GLViewWidget ` and that's how I found the `'viewport'` options. The default option `None` for `viewport` is supposed to take the whole widget but it limits to 1/4 in the lower left corner. And that is the reason I resorted to `viewport` option but it didn't work either. I am a newbie to Python and its libraries (2 days) and it is a total mess given so many of them.

Comment: I think I will ultimately resort to 2D graphics only since it doesn't use OpenGL. 3D does. Or may be VisPy or Plotly for 3D.

MatPlotLib is slow and although everyone seems to swear by it, it want something fast, double buffered like PyQtGraph.

Comment: I'm just facing the same trouble with pyqtgraph 0.10.0 linked to PyQt5 and OS 10.11.6. I confirm that pyqtgraph is much better than matplotlib but I don't know how to deal with with this bug. I cant believe this wasn't solved (october 2018) but I don't see the trick.

Answer (score 1):

GLViewWidget is a subclass of QtOpenGL.QGLWidget, as shown in [PyQtGraph's Doc](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.html).

So, maybe we can use the `view.setFixedSize(WidthOfParent, HeightOfParent)` to adjust the size of viewport while resizing the parent widget.

Answer (score 0):

**For Mac with Retina display:** The problem is probably that Mac is trying to use virtual resolution when doing high DPI scaling whereas pyqtgraph uses physical resolution.

It should have been fixed in the latest pyqtgraph github branch([link](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/pull/516)), but the latest PYPI version hasn't been updated since 2016, so please try pip installing directly from github as per official recommendation:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph
```